# SQL merging 2 rows

Tags: mysql

[image: sqlmerger]

Please see the attached screenshot.

If the `code` field and the `des` both match then select the latest date for the `vendor` and `retail price` fields and then I need to merge `NULL` values in the other fields. value need to merge.

From the data in the above image, I want the result to look like this:

```
135203,United Kingdom,ARS,31501 , 142, Asian Grocery, 8901030373916, India, Bru Gold, 3.59, 25/01/2020
```

With the result above, first there should be a check that `code` and `des` both match. When they match, then it will find the row with the latest `date` row and take that `date`, that `retail price` and `vendor` value from that latest date row and other fields will be merged from both rows - i.e. to eliminate `NULL`s.

advanced thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please be aware that images are frowned upon here for reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)! Also, in future, could you provide your table structure(s) as DDL and your data as DML - or also as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7a16b4a53515bfaa4a24c7dd0177e9a) - but be sure to put that data here as well. Also critical is your version of your MySQL instance - they have introduced many new features recently and the version could be critical for any answser!

Comment: @Vérace thanks for posting those links - very helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that you can do this - the final method of choice may well depend on the structure of your data - you've only provided one sample example - the `NULL`s may well vary from record group (grouped by `code` and `des`) to different record group.

In order to answer your question, I did the following (a fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b352a967a44839e0a258388e05ad27ba)):

Create and populate the table data (please see my comment regarding supplying this as DDL and DML in future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE shop 
(
  id INTEGER,
  country VARCHAR (25),
  vendor  VARCHAR (25),
  vpid    INTEGER,
  deptars INTEGER,
  s_type  VARCHAR (25),
  code    VARCHAR (25),
  origin  VARCHAR (25),
  brand   VARCHAR (25),
  des     VARCHAR (25),
  ret_price FLOAT(6, 2),
  s_date DATE
);
```

I called the table `shop` as you didn't provide a name for it. You also didn't provide one for the field containing `Asian Grocery` so I called it `s_type` (for shop type) and finally, I changed the name of the `date` field to `s_date` (for sale date) - you should **never** use SQL keywords as column or table names - it's confusing and makes debugging difficult.

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO shop VALUES
(NULL, NULL, 'ARS', 31501, 142, NULL,                  '123456789', NULL,    '', 'Bru Gold', 2.59, '2020-01-25'),
(135203, 'UK', 'ARS C&C', NULL, NULL, 'Asian Grocery', '123456789', 'India', '', 'Bru Gold', 3.59, '2018-07-24');
```

Then I ran the following query:

```
SELECT
  MAX(s1.id) AS id,
  MAX(s1.country) AS country,
  MAX(s1.vendor) AS vendor,
  MAX(s1.vpid) AS vpid,
  MAX(s1.deptars) AS deptars,
  MAX(s1.s_type) AS "Shop type",
  MAX(s1.code) AS code,
  MAX(s1.origin) AS origin,
  MAX(s1.brand) AS brand,
  MAX(s1.des) AS des,
  MIN(s1.ret_price) AS "Retail price",
  MAX(s1.s_date) AS "Sale date"
FROM shop s1
GROUP BY s1.code, s1.des;
```

Result:

```
id  country     vendor  vpid    deptars     Shop type   code    origin  brand   des     Retail price    Sale date
135203  UK  ARS C&C     31501   142     Asian Grocery   123456789   India       Bru Gold    2.59    2020-01-25
```

This is the result as requested.

The `brand` field was blank (the empty string and not `NULL`) for both sample records - you may want to use some mechanism (the [`REPLACE`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) function?) to provide a default value. Also, note the use of the [`MIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-min().php) function for the retail price.

There are two other approaches you can take, depending on the structure of your full table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  COALESCE(s1.id, s2.id) AS id, 
  COALESCE(s1.country, s2.country) AS country,
  GREATEST(s1.vendor, s2.vendor) AS vendor,
  COALESCE(s1.vpid, s2.vpid) AS vpid,
  COALESCE(s1.deptars, s2.deptars) AS deptars,
  COALESCE(s1.s_type, s2.s_type) AS "Shop type",
  COALESCE(s1.code, s2.code) AS code,
  COALESCE(s1.origin, s2.origin) AS origin,
  COALESCE(s1.brand, s2.brand) AS brand,
  COALESCE(s1.des, s2.des) AS des,
  LEAST(s1.ret_price, s2.ret_price) AS "Retail price",
  GREATEST(s1.s_date, s2.s_date) AS "Sale date"
FROM shop s1
JOIN shop s2
  ON s1.code = s2.code AND s1.des = s2.des
WHERE 
  COALESCE(s1.id, s2.id)           IS NOT NULL AND 
  COALESCE(s1.country, s2.country) IS NOT NULL AND
  GREATEST(s1.vendor, s2.vendor)   IS NOT NULL AND
  COALESCE(s1.vpid, s2.vpid)       IS NOT NULL;

-- As many "IS NOT NULL"s as you may require depending on your overall table structure
```

The result is the same as for the first query - this one makes use of the `COALESCE` function as described [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/coalesce.php).

Finally, you can use the [`IFNULL`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) function (possibly the least useful of the three approaches - but it may fit your needs?). A discussion of the differences between the two is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528468/what-is-the-difference-bewteen-ifnull-and-coalesce-in-mysql).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  IFNULL(s1.id, s2.id) AS id,
  IFNULL(s1.country, s2.country) AS country,
  GREATEST(s1.vendor, s2.vendor) AS vendor,
  IFNULL(s1.vpid, s2.vpid) AS vpid,
  IFNULL(s1.deptars, s2.deptars) AS deptars,
  IFNULL(s1.s_type, s2.s_type) AS "Shop type",
  IFNULL(s1.code, s2.code) AS code,
  IFNULL(s1.origin, s2.origin) AS origin,
  IFNULL(s1.brand, s2.brand) AS brand,
  IFNULL(s1.des, s2.des) AS des,
  LEAST(s1.ret_price, s2.ret_price) AS "Retail price",
  GREATEST(s1.s_date, s2.s_date) AS "Sale date"
FROM shop s1
JOIN shop s2
  ON s1.code = s2.code AND s1.des = s2.des
WHERE IFNULL(s1.id, s2.id)           IS NOT NULL AND
      IFNULL(s1.country, s2.country) IS NOT NULL AND 
      IFNULL(s1.vpid, s2.vpid)       IS NOT NULL;

-- Again, as many "IFNULL"s as you may require
```

As mentioned at the beginning of this answer, all of the DDL and DML is available on the fiddle here. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717134/how-to-merge-multiple-rows-in-mysql) helpful.

Comment: Hi Verace, its really aprciated for you help. as you mentioned in the result there is small clarification.

Comment: Hi Verace, its really aprciated for you help. as you mentioned in the result there is small clarification. max(sales date) is right but same entity retail price need to update in that row. not min(retail price). say eg: 25/01/20 is max sales date but retailprice on that date 4.59 then record need to update 4.59. not min of both record. thnx

Comment: Could you  put this new information into the question itself -  and please put clearly your desired result (as formatted text) into the question - it's not entirely clear to me from what you've written what exactly it is that you want? Put `@Vérace` into a comment beneath this to let me know that you've added the information. If you've found what I've written so far helpful, please feel free to upvote! 8-)

Comment: due to new in this platform forgive me, i edited qustion with more clarification. thnx